# Stripe Checkout PHP Integration

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm having a great deal of "fun" geting Stripe integration working.

I'm building on an old payments page but had it working on the legacy version of checkout. With the upgrade I've had many issues but the documentation doesn seem to help.

I have the below code running in a single index.php file

```
require('../config.php');

<script>
    // Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production!
    // See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_KEY');

    $checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
        'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
        'line_items' => [[
        'name' => 'T-shirt',
        'description' => 'Comfortable cotton t-shirt',
        'images' => ['https://example.com/t-shirt.png'],
        'amount' => 500,
        'currency' => 'gbp',
        'quantity' => 1,
        ]],
        'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
        'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel',
        ]); 
</script>

<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

<?php stripe = Stripe('pk_test_KEY'); ?>

<li> <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myRedirectFN"><button class="btn btn-buy"> Buy image <?php echo htmlspecialchars(" - from £" . $imagePrice); ?></button></a></li>

            <script> 
            function myRedirectFN() {

                stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                    var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_CXv2tKPq22Bo9o9CaKi6z3nW00ZprVPd08')
                    // Make the id field from the Checkout Session creation API response
                    // available to this file, so you can provide it as parameter here
                    // instead of the {{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}} placeholder.
                    sessionId: '$checkout_session['id']'
                    }).then(function (result) {
                    // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
                    // error, display the localized error message to your customer
                    // using `result.error.message`.
                    });}
            </script>
```

This is everything featured on the [Stripe Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/one-time).

Currently I am receiving an unexpected var error but when i remove the var no further progress.

How should I be structring this code?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm your javascript appears to be incomplete, with the `onclick` handler pointing to a non-existent function. Additionally, you need to make sure you grab the checkout session from the server-side call to provide to the client side request via templating or with a [call back to your server](https://github.com/stripe-samples/checkout-one-time-payments/blob/master/client-and-server/client/html/script.js#L87-L103).

You likely want to do something like: `onclick="myRedirectFn"` and then define that function:

```
function myRedirectFn() {

  stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    sessionId: 'cs_123',
  });

}
```

There is a [complete Checkout sample app](https://github.com/stripe-samples/checkout-one-time-payments), including a [PHP server implementation](https://github.com/stripe-samples/checkout-one-time-payments/tree/master/client-and-server/server/php), that you can refer to and compare you.

Comment: Thanks Nolan, 
I've corrected the code behind the button (i'd missed the onclick error) and updated in my original question. 

The creation of the session is happening earlier in the page. Should it be handled as part of overall config instead?